# About property class in a python

Tags: python, properties, python-2.x

I saw a python snippet as below when seeking for a tutorial to `property` in python:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)

c = Celsius()
```

The author said running this snippet would get the following output

```
Setting value
```

, because during the construction phase of the `Celsius`'s instance (`c`), the `setter` of class member `temperature` is invoked, i.e. `set_temperature()`. This explanation makes sense, however in my own computer, I get nothing as output after running this snippet. Is anything wrong here? My python version is `2.7.6` within Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Note that the first sentence of the [property documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) already answers your question: `Return a property attribute for **new-style classes** (classes that derive from **object**).`

Comment: @MSeifert, yes, got it. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, `class Celsius:` declares an old-style class, for which properties don't work. Use `class Celsius(object):`.